# How to pass result set as input from java to oracle store procedure

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset, ref-cursor

My java program calls an oracle stored procedure on one database server. Get the result set and want to pass that result set to my stored procedure on another database server.

How can I pass the result set as an input parameter to Oracle stored procedure which is accepting a ref cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Either access 1st server from 2nd by using database link or otherwise you need to handle it in your intermediate java code level (which connects to both servers)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Callable statement doesn't have any method to set the resultset as parameter . other way is to Call that procedure which want resultset as parameter call it in pl/sql itself . May be you can use table type also to solve your problem.